# unpack() not available on Lua 5.4?

Tags: lua, unpack

I am reading a few tutorials on Lua and am trying to figure out how to use unpack(). I found an example that goes like this:

```
t = { "the", "quick", "brown" }

print (unpack (t))
```

The output should be "the quick brown". 
What actually happens is this: "stdin:1: attempt to call a nil value (global 'unpack')".

How can I make unpack() work?

My Info:
OS: Mac OS 10.8
Lua: 5.4.2

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Since Lua 5.2 `unpack` function is now at `table.unpack`

> Function unpack was moved into the table library and therefore must be called as table.unpack.

Comment: Thank you very much for the information. This solved my problem.